# What do I do with Vim Bootstrap output file?

Tags: configuration, neovim

Using: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS; Neovim (cannot remember initial install method, although it is activated via `nvim` command)

I was recently pointed toward [this](https://vim-bootstrap.com/) web app for creating Vim and Neovim config files. According to any resources I can find, it is supposed to generate a .vimrc file based on the options that you choose. I ran the app, but the output was a file called generate.vim.

What do I do with this file in order to get a config file for Neovim (init.vim?)

If you couldn't tell I am new to Vim. This app is made to limit distractions like config for noobs like myself, but it looks like my level of 'noob' is a bit too much for them...

Comment: my `.vimrc` file is located in ~ ; ie. `$HOME/.vimrc` or `/home/$USER/.vimrc` (or your home directory).   I have no experience with `neovim` sorry

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out. For any future passersby looking for neovim config: config for Ubuntu is located at $XDG_CONFIG_DIR/nvim/init.vim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by running the 'generate.vim' file with Neovim (chosen from the list of apps given @ the run/download prompt.) For me, the default app was text-editor, which just displayed the file. However, when I switched 'run app with' to neovim, the prompt just immediately disappeared. Afterward, I noticed that there was an init.vim file in the appropriate directory. When I opened Neovim, the plugin mgr was running, and all settings were changed.